# Apache Configure Multiple Site on same IP, to be access remotely

Tags: linux, apache, redmine, vtiger

I have a vps server. LAMP is installed in it.

```
Consider the IP as 99.88.77.66
```

I want to run two application on this site. One is vtiger and other is redmine.

```
Installation Location
redmine: /var/www/html/redmine
vtiger: /var/www/html/vtigerCRM
```

I configured httpd.conf as..

```
ServerName 99.88.77.66:80
```

..

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

..

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

..

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/redmine/public"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias redmine
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/vtigerCRM"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias vtiger
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts as..

```
127.0.0.1       redmine
127.0.0.1       vtiger
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Please help me configure in such a way that, by access `http://99.88.77.66/redmine` -- I would be able to access redmine and by `http://99.88.77.66/vtiger` -- vtigerCRM.

Comment: You do not need vhosts to access two sites via same IP and different folders. Just have one hostname with two folders.

Comment: Hi, I can access via `http://99.88.77.66/vtigerCRM` but when I m doing with redmine , the directory listing is happening. By default redmine documentroot suppose to be `http://99.88.77.66/redmine/public`

Comment: Setup a rewrite for that?

Comment: I don't understand sorry, could you please re-write for me if possible?

Comment: Put in `/redmine/.htaccess`:

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ /public/ [R=301,L]

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to acces it like that, but you can configure,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/vtigerCRM"
ServerName vtigercrm.com
ServerAlias www.vtigercrm.com
```

and the your /etc/hosts(on Linux/mac) or system32/drivers/etc/hosts (on Windows) file add

```
99.88.77.66 vtigercrm.com
99.88.77.66 redmine.com
```

and you will be able to access the websites on your new IP

Comment: Read question, this is not what he wants. He doesn't even need to use Vhosts for what he wants to accoplish.